# Ansible - Вывод результата выполнения команды в Debug

Tags: ansible

Есть такой плейбук:

```
   # Запускаем скрипты test.http.sh и test.dns.sh
   - name: run script test
     shell: "{{ item }}"
     loop:
       - "/home/user/test.http.sh | tail -n1"
       - "/home/user/test.dns.sh| tail -n1"
     register: http_res

   - debug:
       msg="{{ http_res }}"

   - debug:
       msg="{{ http_res.stdout_lines }}"
```

Первый debug-такс отрабатывает нормально, и выводит инфу по результатам выполнения двух скриптов, подставляемых из loop.

Но второй таск вылетает с ошибкой - **The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout_lines'**

Если делаю без loop, а на кадый скрипт отдельный такс - http_res.stdout_lines   отрабатывает норм, и я получаю только результат работы скрипта.

Подскажите, как вывести результат работы каждого скрипта, используя таск с loop.

Comment: А чё там в первом дебаге вообще есть? Я про всякие `rc` и `stdout`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался, выводится так:

```
 - debug:
     msg: {{ http_res.results[0].stdout_lines }}
```